# Ionic 2: Search Filter returns undefined

Tags: angular, search, filter, ionic2

I would like to have a search filter on my page. However, it seems as though it will always return undefined. Below is my Typescript:

```
                        filterItems(searchTerm) {
     this.category.forEach((item) => {
         return item.data.filter((data) =>{
           data.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
         })
      });
 }

   setFilteredItems() {
 this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe(search => {
   this.searching = false;
   this.loadcategory = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);

   if (this.searchTerm == "") {
     this.loadcategory = [];
     this.searchresultcount = "0";
   } else {
     this.loadcategory;
     console.log(this.loadcategory)
   }

 });

}
```

I console.log(this.loadcategory) but apparently it returns as undefined. Is there somewhere in my code where I made an error? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should create a pipe cause this is what pipes are made for. You can look up an example here https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-filter-pipe/blob/master/src/ng2-filter.pipe.ts

Comment: How you use `searchTerm` in template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do have a minor error..your `this.category.filter` call back has a return but `filterItems` does not actually return any value.
Assuming `this.category`is an array, try:

```
        filterItems(searchTerm) { 
        let temp:any[] =[];
        this.category.forEach((item) => { 
        temp.push(...item.data.filter((data) =>{ 
data.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1; 
        }) 
        );

        });
    return temp;//return from function
    }
```